# How can I assign zero to missing variable in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

First of all, thank you for reading it. I am new to Python and learning something new every day. 
I wrote a function where inputs are 4 variables and output are 4 variables.
My problem is variables are getting defined somewhere else and it's calling the script. Now, what if the user only defines 3 variables in that case I automatically want a 4th variable to get assigned zero value. I also included another code that I am trying to use for the same purpose.

```
volsum = vol1 + vol2 + vol3 + vol4

    if vol1n == missing:
       vol1n = 0
    else:
    vol1n=vol1/volsum

    if vol2n == missing:
       vol2n = 0
    else:
    vol2n=vol2/volsum

    if vol3n = missing:
       vol3n = 0
    else:
    vol3n=vol3/volsum

    if vol4n == missing:
       vol4n = 0
    else:
    vol4n=vol4/volsum
```

or maybe using a function

```
def vol(vol1,vol2,vol3,vol4):
    volsum = vol1 + vol2
    vol1n=vol1/volsum
    vol2n=vol2/volsum
    vol3n=vol3/volsum
    vol4n=vol4/volsum
    return vol1n, vol2n,vol3n,vol4n
```

Comment: Give the function arguments default values:  `def vol(vol1=0, vol2=0, vol3=0, vol4=0):`  Then you can call it with any number of arguments from 0 to 4.

Comment: Using global variables is something beginning programmers over-use and something experienced programmers avoid like the plague. Using a function and passing in the arguments is the right way to go. You can either do what @TomKarzes suggests and use default values for named variables, or you could consider passing in a list of values  and writing the function so it can deal with any number of values.

Answer (score 1):

Try Assigning Values when you Define the Fucntion:

```
def vol(vol1 = 0,vol2 = 0,vol3 = 0,vol4 = 0):
    volsum = vol1 + vol2
    vol1n = vol1 / volsum
    vol2n = vol2 / volsum
    vol3n = vol3 / volsum
    vol4n = vol4 / volsum
    return vol1n, vol2n,vol3n,vol4n
```

Now suppose you want to skip `vol2`:

```
variable_assigned = vol(vol1 = 5,vol3 = 2,vol4 = 5)
```

If you require a One-Line (I love creating one):

```
#defining vol()
def vol(*kwargs): return [i/sum(kwargs) for i in kwargs]
# using vol()
#example
vol (1,2,3)
#returns
[0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.5]
# so to assign variables,
#if you give 3 values,
vol1n, vol2n, vol3n = vol(1,2,3)
# if 4,
vol1n, vol2n, vol3n, vol4n = vol(1,2,3,5)
```

---

A little Fun (Not recommended):

- Lets say your `vol1 =1, vol2 = 5 vol3 = 3 ...voln = 10`
- So let:

```
vol = [ 1, 5, 3, ... n values, 10]
```

- Now if you run the following code:

```
for j in range(len(vol)): exec(f'vol{j+1}n = [i/sum(vol) for i in vol][j]')
```

- This code will automatically create your `vol1n, vol2n, ... volnn` variables automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a 0, could it be forgotten? Personally, I don't like typing things out when they don't need to be. Try the `*args` feature out.

```
def vol_func(*args):
    volumesum = sum(args)
    vals = []
    for i in range(len(args)):
        vals.append(args[i] / volumesum)
    return vals
```

`volsumlst = vol_func(2.3, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a variable is defined or not using 'locals' function. Alternatively if variables are defined globally, then you should use 'globals' function.

```
if 'vol1n' not in locals():
    vol1n = 0
else:
    vol1n=vol1/volsum

if 'vol2n' not in locals():
    vol2n = 0
else:
    vol2n=vol2/volsum

if 'vol3n' not in locals():
    vol3n = 0
else:
    vol3n=vol3/volsum

if 'vol4n'  not in locals():
    vol4n = 0
else:
    vol4n=vol4/volsum
```